# discord py "unknown role"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command you have to use to verify and get a role on the server. I searched online but couldn't find anything that helps me.
This is my code:

```
    @commands.command(name="verify")
    async def verify(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        failembed = discord.Embed(title="Verification failed", description="Took too long to verify",
                                  timestamp=datetime.utcnow(), colour=0x206694)
        verificationword = secrets.randbelow(1000000)
        verificationembed = discord.Embed(title="Verification", description=f"Type `" + str(
            verificationword) + "`to verify and get access to the server \nYou have  60sek",
                                          timestamp=datetime.utcnow(), colour=0x206694)
        verificationembed.set_footer(text="Made by Ruko",
                                     icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/861768133149065217.png?v=1")
        verificationdoneembed = discord.Embed(title="Verfication accompplished!",
                                              description=f"You are now verified on the server and have access to the channels",
                                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                                              colour=0x206694)
        verificationdoneembed.set_footer(text="Made by Ruko",
                                         icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/861768133149065217.png?v=1")
        message = await ctx.send(embed=verificationembed)
        check = lambda m: m.author == ctx.message.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
        member = ctx.message.author
        try:
            confirm = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=60)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.edit(embed=failembed)
            return

        if confirm.content == str(verificationword):
            await message.edit(embed=verificationdoneembed)
            role = get(member.guild.roles, name="verified")
            await member.add_roles(member, role)
            return

        await message.edit(content="verification canceled")
```

but when i run the command it gives me this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Laurenz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Laurenz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Laurenz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

But I do have a role called "verifed" and I double checked it, but it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Member.add_roles), add_roles does not take a member obj as an argument.

Instead of `await member.add_roles(member, role)`

try `await member.add_roles(role)`

And if it still doesn't work, make sure your bot has the manage_roles permission.

Comment: If that solved your problem, mind marking it as accepted? ;)